# Шифрование файлов на произвольном носителе

Tags: c++

Мне необходимо написать программу, позволяющую шифровать файлы любого расширения (алгоритм на свое усмотрение), которые находятся либо на жестком диске, либо на USB носителе.

Вопрос: какие библиотеки, API и тд. использовать для получения доступа к файловой системе указанных носителей? В Win Api пока что не нашел ничего подходящего.

**UPD**

Видимо сформулировал вопрос слишком абстрактно. Если конкретно, то мне необходимо получить список всех дисков, выбрать необходимый, получить его структуру папок с файлами, выбрать файл, а затем уже начать его шифрование. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно задать несколько отдельных вопросов: один по получению списка дисков и файлов, другой - по созданию GUI-интерфейса, третий - по алгоритму шифрования. Сейчас вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для доступа к файловой системе Windows можно использовать следующие функции WinAPI:

- [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Позволяет открывать файл как для чтения, так и для записи.
- [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Считывает информацию из файла.
- [`WriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Записывает информацию в файл.
- [`CloseHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Закрывает файл, открытый с помощью `CreateFile`

Однако, можно обойтись и без использования WinAPI, воспользовавшись следующими классами стандартной библиотеки:

- [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) Класс для чтения информации из файла.
- [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) Класс для записи информации в файл.
- [`fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) Класс для чтения и записи информации в файл.

Используя стандартные классы вы избавляетесь от привязки к API конкретной операционной системы, что делает ваш код кроссплатформенным.

Однако, для получения списка дисков и перечисления файлов и каталогов нужно будет использовать платформенно-зависимые функции. Если ограничиться только WinAPI, то можно использовать следующие функции:

- [`GetLogicalDrives`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) или [`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) для получения списка имеющихся в системе логических дисков.
- [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`FindNextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`FindClose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) для поиска первого файла/каталога, поиска последующего файла/каталога и закрытия поиска соответственно.

Что же касается графического интерфейса, то данный вопрос достаточно широк, чтобы на него кратко ответить. Для GUI можно использовать, например, [кросспратформенный фреймворк Qt](http://www.qt.io/) или [MFC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Classes). Кстати, в Qt уже присутствуют кроссплатформенные функции поиска файлов, а также метод `QDir::drives()`, выдающий список логических дисков в Windows.

Comment: Что-то получение списка файлов и каталогов осталось без внимания. Его без winapi или дополнительных библиотек вроде не сделать.

Comment: @Qwertiy  В изначальном вопросе этого нет.

Comment: Я, пожалуй, слишком коротко описал. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @sergey11 Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись и без библиотек. Открываешь файл (для этого нужно знать полный путь и название) и работаешь с ним. [Тут можно почитать про работу с файлами в С++](http://cppstudio.com/post/446/)

```
ifstream fin("F:/somedir/somefile.some"); //Открыть файл, лежащий в F:/somedir/somefile.some
```

Чтобы работать с любым типом, открывай в бинарном режиме (`ios_base::binary`):

```
ifstream fin("F:/somedir/somefile.some", ios_base::binary);
```

В дополнение на уточнение об интерфейсе и т.п.:

Есть библиотека Qt, которая позволяет все это делать.

[Работа с файлами и директориями в Qt](http://qt-doc.ru/qt-files.html)

[Пользовательский интерфейс в Qt](http://qt-doc.ru/user-interface.html)

Comment: Забыл написать, подразумевалось наличие минимального интерфейса, в котором можно выбрать носитель, выбрать файл и еще кнопка для начала шифрования. Вот отсюда у меня и вытекает вопрос, как получить список всех дисков, включая съемные, после выбора носителя получить список директорий и файлов, чтобы можно было выбрать конкретный файл для шифрования.

Comment: Список дисков - `GetLogicalDriveStrings`. Поиск файлов - `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile`.

Comment: А вот с этим уже интереснее. Насколько я помню (могу ошибаться), в Qt можно все это сделать, начиная от внешнего вида заканчивая работой с файлами.

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв Можно. Сам такое делал. `QFile` для чтения/записи, `QDir::drives()` для списка дисков.